# How to match two groups with different surroundings? C++

Tags: c++, regex

I would like to parse strings like `(X->Y)` or `[X=>Y]`, and extract the X and Y parts. I did it like this:

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

int main()
{
  std::string text1 = "(X->Y)";
  std::string text2 = "[X=>Y]";

  std::regex my_regex("\\(([A-Z]+)->([A-Z]+)\\)|\\[([A-Z]+)=>([A-Z]+)\\]");
  std::smatch reg_match;

  if(std::regex_match(text1, reg_match, my_regex)) {
      std::cout << reg_match[1].str() << ' ' << reg_match[2].str() << std::endl;
  } else {
      std::cout << "Nothing" << std::endl;
  }


}
```

It works with `text1`, but it gives an empty result with `text2`. What do I wrong? Why isn't X and Y in `reg_match[1]` and `reg_match[2]` if I run the code with text2?

Answer (score 1):

This is because when you are matching `text1`, groups 1 and 2 gets matched:

```
\\(([A-Z]+)->([A-Z]+)\\)|\\[([A-Z]+)=>([A-Z]+)\\]
    ^^^^^^     ^^^^^
```

Whereas in `text2`, groups 3 and 4 gets matched:

```
\\(([A-Z]+)->([A-Z]+)\\)|\\[([A-Z]+)=>([A-Z]+)\\]
                             ^^^^^^     ^^^^^
```

So you have to use `reg_match[3]` and `reg_match[4]` in the case of `text2`.

Of course, a more versatile solution would be to check whether `reg_match[1]` is empty first. If it is, use group 1 and 2, otherwise, use group 3 and 4.

Comment: But in this case if I extend the regex with a new entry, I have manually check two more elements from `reg_match`

Comment: @IterAtor As you can see, Turtlefight has written an answer that contains only 2 groups, but their regex matches more than your original regex does. I am not sure whether your regex can be rewritten with only 2 groups. But you could always just put all the alternatives in an array, loop through the array and check each alternative.

Comment: @IterAtor Try this regex: `(?=\([A-Z]+->[A-Z]+\)|\[[A-Z]+=>[A-Z]+\])[[(]([A-Z]+)(?:->|=>)([A-Z]+)[)\]]`. It uses only 2 groups, but it's quite troublesome to add new alternatives. If I were you I would just go with a for loop that loops through all the alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to the given answer by @Sweeper you could rewrite your regex to only have 2 match groups:

```cpp
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

int main()
{
  std::string text1 = "(X->Y)";
  std::string text2 = "[X=>Y]";

  std::regex my_regex("[[(]([A-Z]+)(?:->|=>)([A-Z]+)[)\\]]");
  std::smatch reg_match;

  if(std::regex_match(text1, reg_match, my_regex)) {
      std::cout << reg_match[1].str() << ' ' << reg_match[2].str() << std::endl;
  } else {
      std::cout << "Nothing" << std::endl;
  }
}
```

This however has the small disadvantage that it will also match a few more variants:

- `(X=>Y)`
- `[X->Y)`
- `(X=>Y]`
- etc...